# prevent retain cycle in Swift function pointers

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

How do I prevent a retain cycle when passing around functions as objects in Swift

Imagine you have a datasource object like this

```
import UIKit
class MagicDataSource:NSObject,UITableViewDatasource {

    deinit {
        println("bye mds")
    }

    //cant use unowned or weak here
    var decorator:((cell:CustomCell)->Void)?

    func tableView(tableView:UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell

        decorator?(cell)
        return cell
    }

}
```

And a view controller like this which has (and wants) a strong ref to that object

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var datasource:MagicDataSource? = MagicDataSource()

    deinit {
        println("bye ViewCon")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        datasource?.decorator = decorateThatThing
    }

    func decorateThatThing(cell:CustomCell) {

        //neither of these two are valid             
        //[unowned self] (cell:CustomCell) in
        //[weak self] (cell:CustomCell) in

        cell.theLabel.text = "woot"

    }
}
```

When you discard the view controller , the datasource will not be released and neither will the view controller  as it holds a strong ref to the `decorateThatThing` function on the view controller.

You can stop the cycle and get the decorator to release by doing this in `ViewController` but it feels messy

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
     datasource?.decorator = nil
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    datasource?.decorator = decorateThatThing
}
```

so the question is how do i declare vars and/or functions to avoid having to teardown the datasource manually so that when the view controller is discarded the associated datasource is released too.

Comment: Doesnt work . I want the view controller to own the data source. If its weak it gets discarded at instantiation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than

```
datasource.decorator = decorateThatThing
```

You can use

```
datasource.decorator = { [unowned self] cell in
    self.decorateThatThing(cell)
}
```

Comment: FYI using `unowned` will cause a crash if `self` was deallocated when `decorator` is invoked. You can also use `weak` in the [capture list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID57).

Comment: Yep, if there is _any_ chance that `self` could be deallocated while `decorator` is invoked, then definitely use `weak`. But if that is not possible, then use `unowned`. Using `weak` isn't expensive, but it also isn't free.